# How to Use an HTML element from another HTML page

Tags: jquery, razor, bootstrap-modal

i'm trying  to display  informations about Patient(Model) using a Modal(bootstrap).
i have 2 cshtml pages in the first page i have my link to the modal in the second cshtml page.
in the second page  i have the definition of the modal .

```
 <li><a id="lienDemandes" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal :ID OF THE MODAL IN TTHE SECOND PAGE">Demandes  Patient</a></li>
```

the definition of the modal in the sceond page

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>This is a large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

i need to get the id element for the modal from the second cshtml page to passit for the attribute data-target in the first page.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the second file, you you could try using ajax to `.load()` the file´s data using jQuery into a `div` and toggle it with your anchor.

Another way is using `window.open()`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi Josué i've already tried with .load() <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
 $('#Lnk').load('Page2.cdhtml #MyModal');
}); and it didn't work

Comment: You don't have to specify "#MyModal" on the `.load()`. Here is the docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/ . Also, try checking the response in the console on the developer tools of your web browser.